# pyodbc stored procedures / Microsoft SQL Server error 42000

Tags: python, mysql, sql-server, stored-procedures, pyodbc

I'm working on a script to automate a file load procedure.  So, naturally I need to perform some stored procedures that already exist.  I'm using pyodbc to connect to my database.  I can `SELECT` perfectly fine from the database, but when I try to execute from the database I get this error:

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]
      Syntax error, permission violation, or other nonspecific error (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

I can't figure out what the problem here is - the user has full DB admin permissions, the syntax is correct based off what the pyodbc official documentation says.

```
print("Executing SP")
conn.execute('{EXEC TEMP.s_p_test}')
print("SP Executed.")
```

Here, `TEMP` is the schema for the type of stored procedure in that specific database. I.e., it's the full name of the stored procedure.  I feel like it's probably something stupidly obvious that I'm just missing.

Comment: How did you create `conn`?  Are you using trusted_credentials?

Comment: I was using UID and PWD. I changed that to Trusted_Connection and it didn&#39;t change anything. I also removed the { } from the command and now it works. Thanks for reaching out to help. The documentation threw me off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried a couple of things to fix it.  As @Brian Pendleton suggested, I had tried to change from an explicit database user defined via `UID` and `PWD` to `trusted_connection=True`.  Unfortunately that did not change anything.

However, out of curiosity I decided to see what taking the curly braces out of the function call would do.  The execution worked immediately and produced the desired output.  It would seem that the documentation at pyodbc's wiki either shows bad examples or I found a bug I don't know how to replicate because I don't know what makes my situation abnormal.

Or, in other words, instead of

```
conn.execute('{EXEC TEMP.s_p_test}')
```

I used

```
conn.execute('EXEC TEMP.s_p_test')
```

Comment: That was going to be my next suggestion.  I use stored procs all the time from pyobdc, and I never added the curly braces, so I never ran into this problem.  Glad you fixed it.

Comment: Just another recommendation: it seems you are using a fairly old driver (`10.0`). You might consider using `11.0` as it has better support for UTF-8 conversion in Python 3.

Comment: The problem was using curly brackets with `EXEC`. The ODBC standard method of calling a stored procedure is to use curly brackets with the `CALL` keyword.

Comment: For me without curly braces, it gives the error as 
```pyodbc.ProgrammingError: No results.  Previous SQL was not a query
```

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this issue while I'm trying to execute a sql query inside python script where table name needs to taken from tuple during iterations. I tried multiple methods like using back ticks, square brackets as escape character also, as I thought the error is due to curly braces. Finally its due to formatting issue (even though table name is in string). I used- f"select * from {source_table}" then I'm able to get desired output.